While installing shadcn...i gave wrong directory. Instead of globals.css, I gave globals/css.How to run it correctly again.I am getting a error
PS C:\Users\krith\OneDrive\Desktop\Colbook> npx shadcn-ui@latest init




√ Which style would you like to use? » Default
√ Which color would you like to use as base color? » Slate
√ Would you like to use CSS variables for colors? ... no / yes
✔ Writing components.json...
⠸ Initializing project...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'C:\Users\krith\OneDrive\Desktop\Colbook\src\globals\css'
PS C:\Users\krith\OneDrive\Desktop\Colbook> npx shadcn-ui@latest init




√ Which style would you like to use? » Default
√ Which color would you like to use as base color? » Slate
√ Would you like to use CSS variables for colors? ... no / yes
✔ Writing components.json...
⠸ Initializing project...EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'C:\Users\krith\OneDrive\Desktop\Colbook\src\globals\css'
How to clear this problem????
